# Hibernate merge make both insertion and deletion

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am really new with Hibernate.
Here is my problem:

I have a central DB that regroup data from a lot of agents.

Each agent must store into his own DB only the data that concern him.

I need to synchronize data between server / agent

I have 2 cases:

1) first synchronization ( the DB on the agent is empty)

2) full synchronization ( deletion / new elements added /change etc...)

I have a box entity and user entity the relation between them is many-to-many

box entity is described (partially) like this:

```
 @Entity
//@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name="box")
@NamedQuery(name="Box.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM Box b")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Box extends BasicData implements Serializable {
....

//bi-directional many-to-many association to User
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="boxs")
private Set<User> users;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to BoxUser
@OneToMany(mappedBy="box", orphanRemoval=true)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<BoxUser> boxUsers;

getters /setters
....
```

BoxUser entity is described (partially) like this:

```
public class BoxUser implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private BoxUserPK id;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Box
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="boxid", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private Box box;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userid", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private User user;

    getters /setters
    ....
```

User entity is described (partially) like this:

```
public class User extends BasicData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to BoxUser
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Set<BoxUser> boxUsers;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Box
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="box_user"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="userid", nullable=false)
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="boxid", nullable=false)
            }
        )
    private Set<Box> boxs;

    getters /setters
    ....
```

When I try to save / update (I am using the merge method) the data on agent side i saw that the data is inserted but immediately deleted.

I am not understanding why. Here the output of the hibernate:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        box_user
        (role, boxid, userid) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
2015-05-20 15:14:23.818 TRACE: org.hibernate.type.EnumType - Binding [ADMIN_BOX] to parameter: [1]
2015-05-20 15:14:23.819 TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2015-05-20 15:14:23.819 TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [4]
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        box_user 
    where
        userid=?
2015-05-20 15:14:23.831 TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4]
```

Here the method that make the synchronization:

```
private void synchroUser(Box internalBox, Long boxId)
{

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    BoxUser[] remoteBUList = restTemplate.getForObject(DOMITIK_URL + RestURIConstant.DOMITIK_WS + "getboxuserbyboxid/{boxid}" ,BoxUser[].class,boxId);
    if(internalBox == null)
    {
        boolean firstAdd = true;
        for (BoxUser curBoxUser : remoteBUList)
        {
            // this avoid to save more than one time the box (exception occurred if trying to save several time.
            if(!firstAdd)
                curBoxUser.setBox(null);

            boxUserService.mergeElement(curBoxUser);
            firstAdd = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        List<BoxUser> localBUList = boxUserService.findAll();

        //deleting users that were removed from server  
        for (BoxUser localBoxUser : localBUList)
        {
            boolean userFound = false;
            for (BoxUser remoteBoxUser : remoteBUList)
            {
                if(localBoxUser.getUser().getId() == remoteBoxUser.getUser().getId())
                {
                    userFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!userFound)
                userService.deleteElement(localBoxUser.getUser());
        }

        //adding new users
        for (BoxUser curBoxUser : remoteBUList)
        {
            boolean userFound = false;
            for (BoxUser localBoxUser : internalBox.getBoxUsers())
            {
                if(localBoxUser.getUser().getId() == curBoxUser.getUser().getId())
                {
                    userFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!userFound)
            {
                curBoxUser.setBox(null);
                boxUserService.mergeElement(curBoxUser);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am really stuck and need to understand what I am doing wrong...

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem.

The problem was the multiple cascade definition over the classes.

I removed the cascade on Box entity and leave it on the Box entity:

```
public class Box extends BasicData implements Serializable {
....

//bi-directional many-to-many association to User
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="boxs")
private Set<User> users;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to BoxUser
@OneToMany(mappedBy="box")
private Set<BoxUser> boxUsers;
```

And leave it on BoxUser entity

```
public class BoxUser implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private BoxUserPK id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(nullable=false)
private UserRole role;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Box
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="boxid", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private Box box;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to User
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="userid", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
private User user;
```

Now it's work fine.

Since i am new on hibernate I hope that is the good solution

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that in your configuration you have property `hbm2ddl.auto` with value  `"create-drop"` which automatically delete data and drop schema after end of the session

Comment: No
Here my config for the bean:

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
     
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
     <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domitik.domitikCDB.model" />
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>

         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>

         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

         <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
   <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
       </props>
     </property>
   </bean>

Comment: @Shalom Ohayon you could add code that invoke save/update methods